# How create a object when a user register

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm extending User Model to add two extra fields. How can automate the creation of the Profile class when the user registers. And access data later to modify them.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_dem = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=9,null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Django signals to hook into the `post_save` receiver of the `User` class.

```
def create_default_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_default_profile, sender=Auction)
```

After you create the user you will be able to query for the profile.

```
user = User.objects.create(...)
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parr's solution is asynchronous, that is, there might be a delay between the different objects that you are creating.

A synchronous solution could be to overwrite the `save()` method on the model, to create the other object there.
Example:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_profile = Profile(tipo=f"Customer")
        new_profile.save()
        self.profile_id = new_profile
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```